# Sliding window operation with arbitrary slide distance and no loops (matlab)

Tags: performance, matlab, sliding-window

I am trying to completely vectorize a sliding window operation that involves an arbitrary slide distance in order to minimize the run time for this code.

I have two vectors: (1) A time vector which records in sample number a series of event times and (2) A channel vector which indicates on which channel each event time was recorded. So:

```
time = [1,13,58,96,1002];
channel = [1,1,1,2,2];
```

Which means, for example, that an event was detected at sample number 1 on channel 1. I want to calculate a sliding event count with an arbitrary slide length. For example, if there were only one channel, it would look something like this:

```
binary = sparse(1,time,1,1,max(time));
nx = max(time);  %length of sequence
nwind = <some window size>;
noverlap = <some size smaller than nwind>;
ncol = fix((nx-noverlap)/(nwind-noverlap));    %number of sliding windows
colindex = 1 + (0:(ncol-1))*(nwind-noverlap);  %starting index of each
idx = bsxfun(@plus, (1:nwind)', colindex)-1;
eventcounts=sum(binary(idx),1);
```

I was wondering whether (1) anyone has an idea how to expand this for multiple channels without adding a loop? and (2) perhaps there is an even faster way of making the calculation in general?

Thanks a lot for any ideas. :)

Here is a sample solution without vectorization:

```
fs = 100; %number of samples in a window 
lastwin = max(time);
slide = fs/2; %slide by a half a window 
winvec = 0:slide:lastwin; 
for x=1:max(channel) 
 t = histcounts(time(channel==x),winvec); 
 t = conv(t, [1,1], 'same'); %convolve to get window size of fs 
 eventcounts(x,:) = t;
end
```

Ideally, the script would return an `[MxN]` array, called `eventcounts`, where `M` is the total number of channels and `N` is the total number of windows `numel(winvec)`. In each position `(i,j)`, `eventcounts(i,j)` would contain the number of events for channel `i` and window `j`.

Comment: So, to make it clear, what would the result be for the example `time` and `channel` given in your question?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @LuisMendo . I've updated the question with a sample solution and the expected output.